# $X\setminus X_0$ is finite where $X_0$ is maximal element as a consequence of Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove (as an exercise) that for an infinite set $A$ we have $A^2\sim A$.

> The exercise define $\mathscr{F}:=\{(X,f): X\subset A \quad\mbox{and}\quad f:X\to \{0,1\}\times X \quad\mbox{a bijection and}\quad \vert\Bbb{N}\vert\le \vert X\vert\}$ and an ordered relation as $(X,f)\le(Y,g)$ if $X\subset Y$ and $g$ restricted to $X$ is $f$.

I used Zorn's lemma to deduce that there exists a maximal element noted $(X_0,f_0)$ where $X_0=\bigcup_{(X,f)\in\mathcal{C}}X$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a the totally ordered set included in $\mathscr{F}.$

*Now,* I am supposed to use the maximal element to prove that $X\setminus X_0$ is finite. However, I must be confused, because if $X\setminus X_0$ is infinite then it's in $\mathscr{F}$.

Then, we must have $(X\setminus X_0,f)\le (X_0,f_0)$ which implies that $f_0$ is not a map.

Am-I correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $X\setminus X_0$ is infinite. Then there is an injection $i:\Bbb N\to X\setminus X_0$; let $X_1=i[\Bbb N]$. There is a bijection $h:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}\times\Bbb N$; use it and $i$ to get a bijection $f_1:X_1\to\{0,1\}\times X_1$. Then $f_0\cup f_1$ is a bijection from $X_0\cup X_1$ to $\{0,1\}\times(X_0\cup X_1)$, so $\langle X_0\cup X_1,f_0\cup f_1\rangle\in\mathscr{F}$. But clearly $\langle X_0,f_0\rangle<\langle X_0\cup X_1,f_0\cup f_1\rangle$, contradicting the maximality of $\langle X_0,f_0\rangle$. Thus, $X\setminus X_0$ must be finite.

Comment: I was confused, I get the bijection $f_1$ but not $f_0\cup f_1$, nice, thanks.

Comment: @JeSuis: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The order on the set $\mathscr{F}$ is not total. Zorn's lemma just requires a partial order. Also your outline of proof is not really good.

What you have to do is proving that any totally ordered subset $\mathscr{C}$ of $\mathscr{F}$ admits an upper bound; this will be the pair formed by the union of the first terms in the elements of $\mathscr{C}$ and the obvious map. This will not generally be a maximal element, but the existence of an upper bound for every chain allows to apply Zorn's lemma and to obtain a maximal element.

The maximal element $(X_0,f_0)$ you get satisfies the property that no element of $\mathscr{F}$ is bigger than it, but generally it's false that every element is smaller.

The contradiction instead arises from the fact that we know how to build a bijection $Z\to\{0,1\}\times Z$ when $Z$ is countably infinite. If $X\setminus X_0$ is infinite, it contains a countably infinite subset $Z$. From this you can build an element $(X_0\cup Z,g)\in\mathscr{F}$, which is properly bigger than $(X_0,f_0)$, which contradicts maximality.

Comment: But I didn't say that the order is total just that to use Zorn's lemma, I take  a total ordered set. Thanks for the last part.

Comment: @JeSuis Well, you seemed to be implicitly using it with “we must have $(X\setminus X_0,f)\le(X_0,f_0)$”.